Issues with Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 Wi-Fi Adapter on Ubuntu
I am having trouble getting my Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter to work on my Ubuntu system. The adapter is recognized by the system, but I am unable to connect to any wireless networks.
Here are the details of my setup:

Linux Distribution: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Kernel Version: 6.8.0-47-generic

Output of
lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net: 
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:38a6]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:0901]
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci

Output of ip link show:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9c:5a:44:46:75:b9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enx9af93a54193a: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9a:f9:3a:54:19:3a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Output of dmesg | grep ath10k :  nothing
What I have tried:

Installed firmware packages and confirmed that the ath10k driver is loaded.
Checked for blacklisted drivers and ensured that my Wi-Fi adapter is enabled in BIOS.
Manually copied the necessary firmware files (board-2.bin and firmware-6.bin) to the correct directory.
Edited GRUB settings to include pci=nocrs as a boot parameter.
Updated my system and rebooted multiple times.

